# Extension/tool for calculating how much data is wasted on CSS Class names

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm long held that small class names are more performant based solely on the amount of data put 'on the wire': `.h3title` his *fewer characters* than `.header-for-my-component`.  Local to single usage the difference is tiny, but across an entire site it could be significant.

First, with compression is this an issue?

Second, is anyone aware of an extension that will calculate how much data is being spent *solely* on CSS class/id names?

Comment: Regarding the first question of whether this is an issue, I wouldn't say so. Of all the ways to increase loading performance of a website, counting bytes of text in HTML attributes wouldn't make the list for me - you're probably talking a fraction of a percentage of a website's overall size. If verbose class names are helpful for developers, keep using them.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

there is functionality on devtools called "coverage"

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/coverage/

that make you see how many bytes are used,

 and how many aren't.

[image]

you can also use it to see what selectors aren't useful!

[image]

> the blue lines means: CSS is used
>
>  the red one means: CSS isn't used

Comment: This does not address OP's question of counting characters in CSS class names. This tool counts bytes in unused styles.